# Copy multiple worksheets from workbook and create a new workbook and save this file to new destination with name change and break links

Tags: excel, vba, macos, save, break

I am trying to take multiple worksheets from workbook and save them to a new workbook with a new name and destination. when I have (122, 222) to save multiple worksheets its doesn't let me run it only with one worksheet (122). I also want it to break the link from where it came from originally how can i  include that in this code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Copysheetandsave() 'says error here

    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, savePath As String

    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("215",220") 'wont work with taking two tabs only one

    OneDrive - Consilio\savePath = "C:\Users\"

    sourceWs.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=savePath & "Global App Support 2023 YTD.xlsx"
        
Sub break_link() 'want to include breaking link from new workbook
Acitveworkbook.BreakLink ext_link

        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
``
```

Comment: "says error here" - what exact error message? your posted code is missing an `End Sub`

Comment: Example to copy multiple sheets: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("215","220")).Copy`

Comment: when I run the code it saves everything to a new work but no longer saves it to the destination I need it to, it started showing Run Time Error '424' object required. I replaced ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("215",220") with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("215","220")).Copy and no longer renames the workbook

Comment: "when I run the code" Your code as-posted can't be run, so it's not going to be clear to us what the exact problem might be.  Consider editing your question to add your complete code, and indicate which line is the problem